# partially initialized module 'router' has no attribute 'FindCorrectRoute' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python

I try to call from **main.py** a function in **router.py** that will call a function in **calculator.py** that will try to modify a variable in **main.py**

Something that in C# is achieved for example by creating a public static variable, I don't know how to achieve it in Python.

This is my file **main.py**:

```
import router

# create a table
global mytable
mytable = []

router.CallAnotherFunction("testing data")
```

This is my file **router.py**:

```
import calculator

def CallAnotherFunction(sample_data):
    calculator.ModifyMainTable(sample_data)
```

This is my **calculator.py**:

```
import main

def ModifyMainTable(sample_data):
    main.mytable = sample_data
```

This is the error I'm getting just when trying to execute `router.CallAnotherFunction("testing data")`:

```
AttributeError
partially initialized module 'router' has no attribute 'FindCorrectRoute' (most likely due to a circular import)
  File "C:\Users\dimitri\Documents\Upwork\Footyamigo\main.py", line 37, in <module>
    router.FindCorrectRoute(odd, next_match, local_data, visitor_data)
  File "C:\Users\dimitri\Documents\Upwork\Footyamigo\calculator.py", line 3, in <module>
    import main
  File "C:\Users\dimitri\Documents\Upwork\Footyamigo\router.py", line 1, in <module>
    import calculator
  File "C:\Users\dimitri\Documents\Upwork\Footyamigo\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    import router
```

What I really need is that **mytable** is accesible from all files and if I change it's value from any file I have to see the changes reflected on the others, I don't want to have different instances of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved it `import __main__ as main` inside **calculator.py**